# Collaborative text tool using node.js and socket.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sockets

I am doing a collaborative app with node and sockets which I have a simple text tool. If one of the users types and applies the text to the canvas, I want the other connected user to also see that text.

This is what I tried:

**Client with the text tool**

```
$input.keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ctx.font = (2 * texttool.lineWidth) + "px sans-serif";
    ctx.fillStyle = texttool.color;
    //call fillText to push the content of input to the page
    //this parses out the input's left and top coordinates and then sets the text to be at those coordinates
    ctx.fillText($input.val(), parseInt($input.css("left")), parseInt($input.css("top")));
    //save the context
    ctx.save();
    //set the display to none for the input and erase its value
    $input.css("display", "none").val("");

    console.log("sendtxt: ");
    socket.emit('txt', ctx.fillText());
  }
});

socket.on('txt', function() {
    console.log("Text");
    ctx.fillText();
});
```

**Server**

```
socket.on('txt', function() {
   console.log("Text");
   socket.broadcast.emit('txt', ctx.fillText());
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing fully what cox fill text is doing, Can you try this in the server code. Also I assume ctx.fillText() without params will return the current text.

Client

```
$input.keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ctx.font = (2 * texttool.lineWidth) + "px sans-serif";
    ctx.fillStyle = texttool.color;
    //call fillText to push the content of input to the page
    //this parses out the input's left and top coordinates and then sets the text to be at those coordinates
    ctx.fillText($input.val(), parseInt($input.css("left")), parseInt($input.css("top")));
    //save the context
    ctx.save();
    //set the display to none for the input and erase its value
    $input.css("display", "none").val("");

    console.log("sendtxt: ");
    socket.emit('txt', $input.val());
  }
});

socket.on('txt', function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    ctx.fillText(msg);
});
```

Server

```
socket.on('txt', function(msg) {
   console.log(msg);
   socket.broadcast.emit('txt', msg);
});
```

Comment: fill text should be what applies the text to the canvas. It didn't work tho :/

Comment: I have changed the send val to $input.val().Please check if the character is sent and received in the console.log

Comment: Still didn't work, but I think you might be right sending the $input.val(). The other users will gets the fillText.